# Finding the farthest point within a cube from a set of $n$ other points

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, spheres

I have a cube $C$ in 3 dimensions.  The length of each side is 1, and it is centered at the origin.  I have a set of $n$ points within the volume of this cube.  I am trying to find the point $p$ within the volume of this cube that is the farthest from all $n$ points.  I define farthest using the following procedure:

Imagine that each of the $n$ points is represented by a sphere $s_i$ (where $0 \leq i \leq n$) of radius $r = 0$ at their location in 3-dimensional space.  Imagine that the radius $r$ of each sphere gradually grows until the volume of the cube $C$ is entirely occupied by the combined volumes of each sphere $s_i$.  What is the last point/s in the volume to be occupied?  This is the farthest.

Is there a general formula for this?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there is a general formula (the problem reeks of optimization), but an algorithm should be possible to construct.

Comment: "...until the volume of the cube $C$ is entirely occupied by the combined volumes of each sphere $s_i$" What do you mean by "entirely occupied"? Does this mean that, if I put a point in the center, since it's the furthest from the cube's corners, that's the "furthest" point?

Comment: @LarryB. If the set of points $n$ has no elements, then there would be no furthest point.  My definition of furthest requires the set of points $n$ to have at least one entry.  If the set of points $n$ has exactly one point at the origin, then each vertex would equally be furthest.  If the set of points $n$ has one point at every vertex of the cube, then the origin would be furthest.  These are some trivial examples.

Comment: how would you do this in a segment of length one? dimension 1 rather than 3

Comment: @WillJagy Every two neighboring points has a midpoint.  Find the midpoint that has the longest distance from either neighbor.  Include the points (at the edge) of the segment in the set of midpoints.  So, in a sense, my question is about trying to minimize how close it is to any one point while staying within bounds.

Comment: @PaulTerwilliger: Another way to define this problem would be something like "Find the point within the unit cube centered at origin, that is furthest from any of the *n* known points." The distance to the closest point is what matters; and maximizing that distance, while keeping to within the cube, is the issue. I don't think there is a formula, either, but even I can think of several approaches to constructing an efficient algorithm to finding such a point numerically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Construct a three-dimensional [Voronoi diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) out of the set of $n$ points. You can see from the animation of a two-dimensional Voronoi diagram's "growing sphere" visualization. Let this motivate the solution below.

[image]

Each point $x_i$ will be associated with a convex Voronoi polyhedron $P_i$, for which the points within that polyhedron are closest to that point. Since $P_i$ is convex, its vertices $V(P_i)$ are the furthest points which are closest to $x_i$. Note: These aren't strictly $P_i$, but really the intersection of $P_i$ and the cube. Since we are taking the intersection of two convex polyhedra, the result is still convex.

Let $p_i$ be the point in $V(P_i)$ with the maximum distance from $x_i$, and choose $p$ to be the $p_i$ with the greatest distance from its respective $x_i$.

Comment: Splendid animation. Can you say which software you have used ?

Comment: I did an image search for "voronoi diagram" and restricted the search to animated GIFs. This was one of the first search results.